# Split an observable into overlapping groups then combine them

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, reactivex

Given a sequence of integers, I want to split it into different groups based on a set of conditions:

- The set of conditions may change
- Each element may belong to zero, one or more groups. Meaning these groups can overlap each other.

For example, the code below splits sequence `1..12` into two groups of multiples of 2 and 3:

```
    final Observable<Integer> divisors = Observable.just(2, 3, 4);
    Observable.range(1, 12)
            .flatMap(i -> divisors
                    .filter(divisor -> i % divisor == 0)
                    .map(divisor -> new Pair<>(divisor, i))
            )
            .groupBy(pair -> pair.fst)
            .subscribe(group -> group.subscribe(pair -> System.out.println("element: " + pair.snd + ", group: " + pair.fst), Throwable::printStackTrace));
```

Output:

```
element: 2, group: 2
element: 3, group: 3
element: 4, group: 2
element: 4, group: 4
element: 6, group: 2
element: 6, group: 3
element: 8, group: 2
element: 8, group: 4
element: 9, group: 3
element: 10, group: 2
element: 12, group: 2
element: 12, group: 3
element: 12, group: 4
```

My questions are:

1. Notice that in the above example, we have only 1 condition set `divisors`. How to update it later on? I think a changing variable can be naturally thought as a hot observable. But in this case, I have no idea how to use a hot `Observable<Observable<Integer>>` in the second observable.
2. How to combine the split groups in a specific order, like `join`?
3. Is there a better solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the `groupBy` use, the normal pattern is to combine it with flatMap:

```
o.groupBy(...)
 .flatMap(g -> g.whatever())
```

Having said that you also mention that items emitted by the source can appear in multiple groups. Use `flatMap` to make that happen before the `groupBy`. For instance the number 6 you might `flatMap` to `Observable.just(Multiple(2, 6), Multiple(3, 6))` then `groupBy` the first element of `Multiple`.

Hopefully this is enough of a start for you.